# How to find resolution display of android phone with navigation

Tags: android, screen-resolution, navigationbar

I am using Nexus 5, which has resolution of 1080 X 1920 . 
I have tried below code snippets

```
1

DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
int screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

2

Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;

3.

public static int getScreenWidth() {
    return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
}

public static int getScreenHeight() {
    return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
}
```

The width is coming as it is 1080.
But for height i'm getting as 1776, with a difference of 144 from 1920, which is the navigation height.

I know a hack to check for if navigation is present or not. But i donot want to do.

Anyone who knows the answer please help.